# Username and Password not accepted when sending mail (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer to send a confirmation email from my site that's hosted on Heroku.
It was working perfectly fine when I typed in my username and password as strings in the smtp_settings, but that's obviously a security flaw since they're up on Github for everyone to see. So today I changed my gmail password and used Heroku's config to save the username and password. My smtp settings now look like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings ={
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "gmail.com",
  user_name: "#{ENV['EMAIL_USER']}",
  password: "#{ENV['EMAIL_PASS']}",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Only every time I try to send mail it gives me a "Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted" error. I even added puts to show the values of the config settings in the console:

```
puts "USERNAME : #{ENV['EMAIL_USER']}"
puts "PASSWORD : #{ENV['EMAIL_PASS']}"
```

and in Heroku's logs they came out perfectly fine. I read the other post about Gmail blocking the login due to suspicious activity but I've had no such alert. It just doesn't work when I use config variables - changing it back to strings made it work on my local development environment. I'm a bit at a loss here. Any ideas?

Comment: can you paste your heroku logs

Answer (score 1):

I've had the SMTPAuth error message you're showing, and I've got a couple suggestions:

First - here is the config that works for me on my production application:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM' }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true;
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "MYDOMAIN.COM",
  :user_name => ENV["MAILER_USER_NAME"],
  :password => ENV["MAILER_PASSWORD"],
  :from => 'SALES@MYDOMAIN.COM',
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true 
}
```

All the MYDOMAIN stuff are my actual credentials.

Second - The thing that threw me was the use of tokens which were interpret by Linux as BASH commands - so here is an EXAMPLE password:

```
ANEXAMPLEPA$$0RD
```

Now when you EXPORT this, either on Heroku or on your own UNIX terminal - you have to surround the password with single quotes to literally interpret the string like so :

```
'ANEXAMPLEPA$$0RD'
```

If you DO NOT do this - the password that you type with export PASSWORD=PWD or the heroku config:add KEY=VALUE will actually drop some of these special characters (UNIX takes $1 and $2 etc as placeholders for variables when you chain commands - this turned out to be my problem).

So make sure that if you're using a password that you feel is strong that any combination of the password won't accidentally be interpreted as a UNIX-level command.  Both export FOO=BAR and heroku config:add FOO=BAR will return without an error, and you'll think your password is set correctly.  Then after an hour you'll check to make absolutely sure the password is correct and you'll notice some interpolation has taken place.

Third - contrary to many posts on SO and personal blogs about the :domain => key being unnecessary and even actually contributing to send failures, I find that it works totally fine with this element.